# realm android Design and Query by JSONArray field value

Tags: android, realm

I have a realm model named **Products** which has a field named **data**.
*data* field is a josn string (array of objects).

**QUESTION 1:** What is the best way to introduce this model by **relam**?

Keep in mind that I want to search products by specific field value in *data* field which is an array of objects. Also objects which stored in *data* field may have different keys!

Below you can see a sample *data* of a product:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 254,
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "ref": 78851,
    "size": "24D"
  },
  {
   "id": 84515,
   "amount": 785
  }
]
```

**QUESTION 2:** How to build a **realm query** to find all products where their *data* field has objects which **amount** is greater than 500 or **size** is "24D".

Comment: I have this problem too

Comment: This is for Q1
`public class Data{
 @SerializedName("id")
 private long ID;
 @SerializedName("name")
 private String Name;
 /**Getters and setters**/
}
public class DataList{
 @SerializedName
 private ArrayList<Data>;
 /**Getters and setters**/
}`

Comment: @FiN Thank you for your comment, but as I mentioned in the question, fields` keys in the data are vary and dynamic. As you see in the sample data structure, we have different keys in it.

Comment: @AhmadAzimi darn...
I didn't read the question then very well... So you mean, that the values in **data** are dynamical...
Realm needs a helper class with corresponding properties of your JSON...so i don't think this is possible.

Comment: @FiN Yes! values in **data** are dynamical. So... Is there and chance to implement it with DynamicRealm?

Comment: [Check this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java)
I think this will be useful to you, especially check where they migrate to new versions.

Comment: what is ref? what is size? Is there a list of possible values you can receive from this really badly designed API?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Actually this is for saving forms data. Each form generates dynamically by user,  I mean form fields added by user and he can create a completely dynamic form with customized fields using our form generator. Then he can use saved forms to gather information by saving those data. We need a table to save those filled forms` data. As you see we can't determine a list of fields and values in any way!

Comment: You could model `data` as a list of key/value pairs: `public class Data extends RealmObject { private String key; private long value; }`. And add a `RealmList<Data>` field to `Product`.